# Redirect from one page to other with href appended to redirected url

Tags: php, jquery, html

In below,i am trying to redirect from one page to another page with href attribute is appended to URL link.

```js
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('a').click(function(){
 var clk=$(this).attr('href');
 //alert(clk);
 window.location='http://www.shopeeon.com&ver='+clk;
 });
});
</script>

<a href="http://www.gogle.com">Google</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.rediff.com">Rediff</a><br/>
```

In above example onclick first i want href(i.e. http://www.google.com,http://www.yahoo.com,..etc) which is stored in 'clk' variable and redirect to another page(i.e. http://shopeeon.com) with our link which is stored in "clk" variable.

In my case when i click on link instead of redirecting to other page with appended link it runs that particular href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better Remove a tag, Have some div tag with data attribute place URL there.

For example,

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').click(function(){
    var clk=$(this).attr('data-href');
    //alert(clk);
    window.location='http://www.shopeeon.com&ver='+clk;
    });
});
</script>

<div data-href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</div><br/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to stop its Default behaviour by using `.preventDefault()`

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/124tLn6a/4/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var clk=$(this).attr('href');
    //alert(clk);
    //window.location='http://www.shopeeon.com&ver='+clk;
    window.location='http://www.shopeeon.com&ver='+encodeURI(clk);
    });
});
```

**[UPDATE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/124tLn6a/6/)**

Comment: Accept as answer if you like it.

Comment: format of appending variable in above (window.location='http://www.shopeeon.com&ver='+clk;) is not work properly

Comment: I didnt get you. can you explain?

Comment: I have added an update fiddle. Might be URL encoding will solve your problem

Comment: in above example i use jquery to other page redirect using "e.preventDefault();", but how i can perform same action using javascript onclick function

Comment: Same code for javascript also. `e.preventDefault()` is not specific to jQuery, its a native javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var clk=$(this).attr('href');

        clk ='http://www.shopeeon.com&ver='+clk;
        alert(clk);
        $(location).attr("href", clk);
    });
})
```

[Google](http://www.gogle.com)
Click on Google to see what is in url to redirect page